# pagination using display tag in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to implement pagination in my application ...

I am getting a arraylist of object from my db and the list name is `detailsList`

Now I have to display the `detailsList` **with pagination** in my jsp page.
This is my action class.

```
public class ViewTestCasesAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -5142928518089123340L;

private String moduleSelected;



private List<TestCaseDetailsBean> detailsList = new ArrayList<TestCaseDetailsBean>   ();



private Map<String, Object> session;


public String execute() {

    detailsList = dbFunction.fetchdetails(moduleSelected);
    session.put("detailsList", detailsList);


    if (detailsList.size() > 0) {

        return SUCCESS;
    }
    return ERROR;
}

public Map<String, Object> getSession() {
     return session;
}
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
     this.session = session;
}
```

Now to display this `detailsList` using the `display` tag, steps must I take? I know that there are many posts regarding this but I am not sure about how to get it. I am using struts2 framework and using jsp in the front end. I tried using the `display` tag but I was not successful.I think the settings are to be made in `struts-config` and `web.xml`.

I am using session aware here to put the list in session scope so that I could display in jsp. Please help me getting the values in display tag.Just help me with the process.

I tried a way out but getting the same error...

I changed my web.xml as..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
  </filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    </jsp-config>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
 org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>config</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>debug</param-name>
<param-value>2</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>detail</param-name>
<param-value>2</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

And I have created a action form also as per a blog which is

package com.harmony.cloud.action;

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import com.harmony.cloud.bean.TestCaseDetailsBean;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class ViewTestCasesForm extends ActionSupport {

private ArrayList<TestCaseDetailsBean> detailsBeans;

public ArrayList<TestCaseDetailsBean> getDetailsBeans() {
    return detailsBeans;
}

public void setDetailsBeans(ArrayList<TestCaseDetailsBean> detailsBeans) {
    this.detailsBeans = detailsBeans;
}



}
```

Also  struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">

<struts-config>
<form-beans>
<form-bean name="ViewTestCasesForm"
type="com.harmony.cloud.action.ViewTestCasesForm"/>
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>
<action input="/" name="ViewTestCasesForm" path="/viewAction.do"
scope="session" type="com.harmony.cloud.action.ViewTestCasesAction">
<forward name="success" path="/home.jsp" />
</action>
</action-mappings> 
</struts-config>
```

My JSP looks like this...

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.harmony.cloud.bean.TestCaseDetailsBean" %>
<%@ page import="com.harmony.cloud.action.ViewTestCasesAction" %>

<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Cases List</title>
</head>
<body>
<display:table export="true" id="data"
name="sessionScope.ViewTestCasesForm.detailsBeans"
requestURI="/viewAction.do" pagesize="3">

</display:table>


</body>
 </html>
```

When I execute I get the following error........

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.UnhandledException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.instantiate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.find(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3944)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2209)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1640)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3490)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:250)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:164)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. And don't use the session to store objects that should be stored in the request.

Comment: <% session.getAttribute("detailsList"); %>
<display:table list="detailsList" requestURI="TestAction.action">
 </display:table>

Comment: Do I have to do add anything in web.xml

Comment: Have you read the doc? Show us more than that: the complete (but minimal) JSP page. Tell us what happens. What the generated HTML is. The stack trace of the exception if any.

Comment: @JBNizet I have changed my question and also what I tried ...

Comment: I'm not sure this exception has anything to do with the display tag. Why are you adding a struts-config file, the struts-xxx tag libraries, and ActionServlet, etc? These are for Struts1, which doesn't have anything to do with Struts2 except the name. My advice would be to start from scratch with a simple and clean Struts2 app. Then add the displaytag.

Comment: @JBNizet Do I need to use action form or directly can I use a list from my action class to display tag?

Comment: An ActionForm is a Struts1 thing. You're using Struts2. The displaytag dosn't care whether you use Struts1 or Struts2. All it needs is a list of beans to display.

Comment: Now when I am including the display tag in my jsp...it is throwing the unhandled exception error.

Comment: @JBNizet the stack terrace is showing error about the commons-lang jar but i already have that jar..another thing do we need to include displaytag.TLD and add it to the web.xml

Comment: @JBNizet Now I have solved the excepion by adding the commons-lang.jar

Comment: @JBNizet But I am getting a message now as: Nothing to display

Comment: I changed the display tag code to...
    <display:table export="true" name="detailsList" uid="chartRow"     id="sTable" pagesize="2" class="table" requestURI="">
</display:table>

Answer (score 0):

1. Include displaytag library in your project. [How?](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/install.html)
2. Pass the parameters in the request. You have two options, but the simplest one is to create an attribute `private List<ListDetailsBean> detailsList` with a getter.

   ```
   public TestAction extends ActionSupport {
       ...
       private List<ListDetailsBean> detailsList;
       ...
       public List<ListDetailsBean> getDetailsList () {...};
       ...
       public String execute () {
           ...
           detailsList = whatever ();
           ...
       }
       ...

   }
   ```
3. Finally, use display tag in your jsp with the attribute that you want to show in it. [How?](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/tut_basic.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I have already added all the jars...Could you please tell me the process or if you could provide me the code snippet for the jsp and do I need to do do anything in web.xml?

Comment: @user1901079: That's not how it works here. Show us what *you* tried, explain us what doesn't work, and we'll help you.

Comment: @user1901079 *if you could provide me the code snippet...* **Can you click on the links that I have put in the answer?** Your comment denotes that you are not trying to achieve something, you are simply waiting for someone that will solve it for you.

Comment: @Pigueiras sorry dude my bad I have reframed my question ..please check and help me

Comment: @Pigueiras I have solved the issue but am getting Nothing to display message.

Comment: @user1901079 Are you sure that you have something in the list? Is there something in the log?

Comment: I got it solved I dint include the lang.jar which was the source of error I suppose..